# Can't see text in Storyboard

Tags: lua, storyboard, coronasdk

I am fairly new to Corona SDK and was trying to make a game menu, but when I run the code it just don't display the text.I have know for sure that the program make it's way up to this file. Any idea why?

```
local storyboard =  require ("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

display.setStatusBar (display.HiddenStatusBar)

local function ButtonTap (event)
  storyboard.gotoScene(event.target.goto, {effect="slideDown"})
  return true
end

function scene:CreateScene (event)
  local group = self.view

  -->Play Button
  local PlayBtn = display.newText ("Play",0,0)
  PlayBtn.x = display.contentHeight/2
  PlayBtn.y = display.contentWidth/2
  PlayBtn.goto = "Play"
  PlayBtn:addEventListener("tap", ButtonTap)
  group:insert(PlayBtn)

  -->Exit Button
  local ExitBtn = display.newText ("Play",0,0)
  ExitBtn.x = display.contentHeight/2
  ExitBtn.y = display.contentWidth/2 + 60
  ExitBtn.goto = "Play"
  ExitBtn:addEventListener("tap", ButtonTap)
  group:insert(ExitBtn)
end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end

-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display view)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
  local group = self.view

end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

function scene:CreateScene( event ) should be function scene:createScene( event ) if you follow the standard naming conventions. Lua is case sensitive.  In:

```
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
```

You're using a lowercase "c", but in the function, you use an uppercase "C". These have to match and the Corona standard would be to go with the lowercase version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but sadly the code still does not want to work